# C# List.Add() keeps updating all my entries instead of adding new ones

Tags: c#, list

I have read through all the answers to similar questions and have tried a bunch of different permutations but nothing seams to work! I've spent the last 4-5h trying to get around I keep getting the same result. Please help!

here is my problematic code:
I need to copy the contents of the cruMatrix into cruMatric_tm1 on each iteration. I've left some of the things I've tried commented out

```
while (true)
        {
            //cruMatrix = new List<double[]>();
            //cruMatrix = cruMatrix_tm1.ToList();
            T1 = new Thread(updateCaConcentration); T1.Start(); T1.Join();
            T2 = new Thread(updateSystemState); T2.Start(); T2.Join();


            //cruMatrix_tm1.Clear();
            systemUpdate();
            plotOpenVsTime(ref time); 

            //cruMatrix_tm1 = new List<double[]>(cruMatrix);
            cruMatrix_tm1 = new List<double[]>();
            foreach(double[] arr in cruMatrix){
                cruMatrix_tm1.Add(arr);
            }

            run++;
            if (run > runUntil) break;
            time++;
        }
```

Comment: May be this article [deep cloning objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) may help

Comment: Are you sure that `List<double[]>` is really the type you want to use? What are you doing? Please provide more information

Comment: I'm using this to store information about a set of coordinates, a state variable and one more piece of information so each entire looks like this {x,y, state, level}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double[] is a reference type. When you add the array from one list to another you adding a reference to the *same* array. Any modifications made to the array will be reflected in both lists.
What you want to do is create a new array and use something like Array.Copy like this:

```
cruMatrix_tm1 = new List<double[]>();
foreach(double[] arr in cruMatrix){
    double[] copy = new double[arr.Length];
    Array.Copy(arr,copy,arr.Length);
    cruMatrix_tm1.Add(copy);
}
```

Comment: this looks promising I'll try it when I get back to the lab tomorrow. Thank you!  I was hoping that there is a way to do it without the foreach loop from efficiency considerations since those lists are very long on the order of 1000-10000 entries. Also if this works I'll need to turn **bold**(cruMatrix_tm1) into a `code'(List<List<double[]>>)  in order to store the progress of the system  during the loop iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You keep creating a new List for cruMatrix_tm1 inside the looping, that's why cruMatrix_tm1 always have the same element.

```
//put it outside the loop
cruMatrix_tm1 = new List<double[]>();

while (true)
        {
            T1 = new Thread(updateCaConcentration); T1.Start(); T1.Join();
            T2 = new Thread(updateSystemState); T2.Start(); T2.Join();

            systemUpdate();
            plotOpenVsTime(ref time); 

            foreach(double[] arr in cruMatrix){
                cruMatrix_tm1.Add(arr);
            }

            run++;
            if (run > runUntil) break;
            time++;
        }
```